# Failed to upload huge size file to Office 365 site

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, office365

We have an Office 365 site. When we upload documents of few MB from Browser, they are successfully uploaded to document library but when we tried to upload file of size greater than 50MB, we get the connection closed/interrupted error

in IE, we get:
[image]

in Chrome, we get

[image]

As far as I know, Office 365 support maximum of 250MB file size.
Please let us know, if there is any settings/configuration we need to set either in client or server side.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This question is perfect for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com and I think you would get a better response there.  However, it is not programming related so it doesn't belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for SharePoint online the limit is a single file of 250MB.

Suggestions:

1. Try mapping a drive and dragging and dropping
2. Try using a client tool like SharePoint Workspace
3. Check your outbound firewall timeouts. Maybe try another location?

Thanks
Robert Crane
www.ciaops.com